# KnockoutJS can't set input field to false value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

How can I set the value of an `<input>` to **false**? **true** works fine.

Model:

```
function Model(){
   self = this;
   self.Test = ko.observable(false);
};
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:Test"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `<input type="text">` expects a text value, and you're supplying a boolean.

The boolean value `false` is considering "falsey" when passed in the value attribute, which is the same as supplying *no* value, so it appears blank.

It works for `true` because you end up with `true.toString()`